# Can Windows Storage Spaces Mirror use 5 HDD in JBOD?

Tags: windows, software-raid, windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

I have a 5 disk USB 3.0 enclosure (JBOD configuration, Windows see's 5 physical disks) with a max of 4TB per disk.

I want to make a Windows Storage Spaces in mirrored mode (all data written to 2 disks).

1. Does it matter that i dont have an even number of disks?

How does it work: 5x4TB = 20TB, and because its mirrored 10TB or does it only use 4x4TB = 16TB and mirrored 8TB, with one disk unused?

2. Does it matter if I have all 4 or 5 disk when i create the Storage Pool, or can I add 1/2 disk at a time to increase the pool size? I have read that storage spaces does not re-balance the data?
3. If I cant use all 5 disks for the pool, would it make sense to add the 5th disk as hot-spare?

Comment: As per site rules we assume you did read the documentation (part of the "professional system administration only" and "professional is a mindset". All the questions here are way more than clear in the documentation.

Comment: Hmmm, I have tried to read as much doc as posible. But it would be nice if someone could comment on my questions.

Comment: There certainly are RAID 1+0 implementations which can use an odd number of disks in a sensible way and would give you 10TB of space. Whether the one you are mentioning is one of those is unknown to me. Either way configuring the last as a hot spare would also make sense.